# How to prevent Login in AD B2C based on an extension claim type using custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have an extension claim type say **extension_isEmailVerified**. I want to block user from login based on the value of this claim type. If it is **true** then user can login and if  **false** then need to show an error message in the login page that your email is not verified.

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Above is my sign in technical profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional validation technical profiles to validate the custom attribute and display an error message if it isn't set to the expected value as follows:

(Note that if the **login-NonInteractive** validation technical profile doesn't succeed then the additional validation technical profiles aren't executed.)

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  ...
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Oops, your email hasn't been verified.</Item>
  </Metadata>
  ...
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-AssertEmailVerified" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The **ClaimsTransformation-AssertEmailVerified** technical profile (see [Define a claims transformation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile) for more information about a claims transformation technical profile) is defined as:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Claims Transformation</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimsTransformation-AssertEmailVerified">
      <DisplayName>Assert Email Verified Claims Transformation</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_EmailVerified" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailVerified" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

The **AssertEmailVerified** claims transformation is defined as:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertEmailVerified" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_EmailVerified" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Its working great for a local B2C account. But how can we perform the same thing with a social account login, like a login from a google account?