# How to change SignUpOrSignIn to validate custom attribute on login in Azure AD B2C custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Every user, upon creation, have a custom attribute "IsApproved" which is a boolean to tell if the admin has approved the user to sign-in. It is set to false at the user creation. We don't want an user to be able to login if he is approved. However, I can't find a way to do that.

I've tried working with OrchestrationSteps, skipping the SendClaims one so that the login doesn't complete, but then I arrive on a blank page. I don't know if there's a way to redirect to a new html page or even a better way to do what I intend.

There are the changes I made to the OrchestrationSteps in my TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml to try a redirect to a custom HTML page when the user is not approved (The SendClaims step is skip and I try to do a ClaimsExchange):

```
<UserJourneys>
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_isApproved</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_isApproved</Value>
          <Value>False</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_isApproved</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_isApproved</Value>
          <Value>False</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="RedirectToErrorPage" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="RedirectToErrorPageForIsApproved" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

With the RedirectToErrorPageForIsApproved technical profile being:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Redirect if account not approved</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="RedirectToErrorPageForIsApproved">
      <DisplayName>Redirect if account not approved</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.redirectisapproved</Item>
      </Metadata>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

And the ContentDefinition being:

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.redirectisapproved">
    <LoadUri>https://{Settings:BlobName}.blob.core.windows.net/{Settings:StorageFolderName}/html/Hello_world.html</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>https://{Settings:BlobName}.blob.core.windows.net/{Settings:StorageFolderName}/html/Hello_world.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Redirect if account not approved</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>
```

Everything is in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml. The best way to implement this, even if that's not what I tried here because I didn't know how, would be if there could be a message in red like "You are still not approved" above the email field when entering user credentials (just like it does when invalid password), but I'm open to any suggestion if it makes it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution will give you the experience as it gives for incorrect username or password.

Create **ClaimsTransformation** :

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CompareApprovalAttribute" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
            </InputClaims>
            <InputParameters>
                <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
            </InputParameters>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
```

**Technical Profile:**

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="ApprovalState">
                <DisplayName>Check the User Login State</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CompareApprovalAttribute" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

**Login Technical Profile:**

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        <Item Key="language.forgotpassword_link"></Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">You are not allowed to login</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />               
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />                     
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ApprovalState" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Add below line in the "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" technical Profile:

```
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />
```

Note:

```
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0</DataUri>
```

This Content Definition only calls when there is any unhandled exception in B2C.

Comment: Thanks for that! I also just found a similar solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113121/how-to-prevent-login-in-ad-b2c-based-on-an-extension-claim-type-using-custom-pol
Both are working great (since they are pretty much the same)

Comment: What if I wanted the user the be redirected to the login page and sign up because no user will be approved just after signing up. How could I do that? Now, it logins the user upon sign-up.

Comment: In the flow you can configure a pre-condition step after registration where you check if it is NewUser, an HTML page with details or you can add a link in the page which will redirect to login page. This will help in blocking to get the token. 

Refer this link: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-reset-only

Comment: I'm not sure where to put the precondition and even how to do the redirection to my login page. I also tried the code from the link you sent me and I always get a 500 internal error after the signup. Can't figure why.

Comment: Whether you have a SignUpSignIn flow policy or 2 separate policies of SignUp and SignIn. 

If possible can you share the policy so that I can help you in solving the 500 error.

Comment: Thanks for trying ot help. I made a new thread so this could help more people. You can answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141778

Comment: I have shared the end-to-end code with you in the another thread. 
Hope this will solve your problem. Happy to help you if you still face any issue.