# Azure Active Directory B2C - Add verification to a (default) signup user flow

Tags: validation, azure-ad-b2c

is there a way to add verification to an attribute in a default signup user flow? I have found the column "Requires Verification" at the page layout of the "Local account sign up page". But I can't switch it from No to Yes, because this field is disabled (except the field email address).[image]

Can I activate and define a verification for other fields?

Thank you in forward.

Best regards
Matthias

Comment: What "verification" are you looking to perform on the field?

Comment: That was only an example that I've selected the Given Name. I don't want to verifiy the given name. I want to verify a custom field if the String starts with 3 digits.

Comment: I think you might have what you are looking for here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113121/how-to-prevent-login-in-ad-b2c-based-on-an-extension-claim-type-using-custom-pol

Comment: Hello @FacundoLaRocca, thank you for your answer. I know that I can solve it with this custom policies. But my question was if there is a way to solfe it with the (default) user flows?

Comment: Do you want to verify with regex? or what? You could do front end verification using JS. You can do backend verification using ClaimsTransformations or REST API or both. Front end verification using JS can be done with User Flows. Sign Up verification can be done via API Connectors in User Flows. Otherwise you want Custom Policies.