# How to prevent Login in AD B2C based on an extension claim type using User Flows

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-authentication, msal-react

In my application I have a use case where I want to check my custom attribute (extension) "IsActive" in order to login user. If "IsActive" is false need to redirect to some other public(unauthenticated) page like contact admin or anything.

I got these 2 questions on Stack Overflow but these questions are for custom policies

[How to change SignUpOrSignIn to validate custom attribute on login in Azure AD B2C custom policies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137472/how-to-change-signuporsignin-to-validate-custom-attribute-on-login-in-azure-ad-b/63139333#63139333)

[How to prevent Login in AD B2C based on an extension claim type using custom policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113121/how-to-prevent-login-in-ad-b2c-based-on-an-extension-claim-type-using-custom-pol)

I want solution for UserFlow
I am using SignUpSignIn user flow with msal.js package on react app

I tried few things on react level but I wasn't able to do also I don't feel it is very secured enough If I handle it in FE application.

I think most secure way would be to do on B2C level

Answers for implementing it via react app is also welcomed